# sns.lmplot(x='coursetotal', y='grade', data=ml_full, col='assignment') error

Tags: pandas

My data:

```
In [30]: ml_full.columns
Out[30]: Index([u'coursetotal', u'email', u'assignment', u'grade'], dtype='object')


In [32]: ml_full.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 496 entries, 0 to 495
Data columns (total 4 columns):
coursetotal    496 non-null float64
email          496 non-null object
assignment     496 non-null object
grade          270 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 15.6+ KB.
```

Then I try and plot it and get this error:

```
In [33]: sns.lmplot(x='coursetotal', y='grade', data=ml_full, col='assignment')

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:16157)()

ValueError: low >= high
```

I've reduced this to a small case. There are definitely NaN's in the data by the way in case that's what the problem is. I don't know how to further diagnose what the problem is with my data. Any tips?

Comment: in python3 you can't add strings & numbers (but you could in python2).  So I think that's the message, but don't know exactly what is happening behind the scenes with lmplot, but make sure your data is as you expect, maybe try converting strings to either categoricals or numbers?

Comment: I see that the `grade` column is of type `object` instead of numeric. Does it by any chance contain strings that sometimes contain `+` and `-` signs, e.g., `B+`, `C-`? If so, you need to map the grades to a numeric data type in order to plot them.

Comment: Thanks... I fixed that, and now I get: `ValueError: low >= high`... See above...

Comment: @pitosalas: This is an old post, but any chance that you have the solution? ;)